# Maximum subarray sum of given length range

Tags: arrays, greedy-algorithms, maximum-subarray

Can anyone please help me solve this better than $O(|a-b| \cdot n)$?

Given an array of both negative and positive numbers, we want to find the maximum sum of the elements in contiguous subarray having a length **between** $a$ and $b$.

Example

Input:

8 1 2

-1 13 -2 5 13 -5 2 2

Output:
18

Here a = 1 , b = 2

Although Maximum sum is 29, Max sum of length between [1-2] is 18

Prob : https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer explains an $O(n)$-time algorithm.

#### Basic Ideas

The ideas are classic.

- "Sum of the elements in subarray" -- prefix sums.
- "Length between `a`and `b`" -- window of size `b-a+1`.
- "Maximum" -- maximum queue for the window

We will compute the array of prefix sums `prefix_sums` first. Then for each index `s`, we will compute the maximum elements of `prefix_sums[s+a..s+b]`. The difference between `prefix_sum[s]` and that maximum element is the maximum sum of a subarray that starts at index `s + 1` and of length between `a` and `b`.

To compute the maximum element of `prefix_sums[s+a..s+b]`, we will keep  a dequeue of elements like `(prefix_sums[i], i)`, decreasing in the `pref_sums[i]` part but increasing in the `i` part. When `s` is increased by 1,
we will remove `(prefix_sums[s+a-1], s+a-1)` from the front of the dequeue if that element is in the dequeue, as well as append `(prefix_sums[s+b], s+b)` to the dequeue, popping out all previous elements with no greater prefix_sum-part from the back of the dequeue. Hence the maximum element of the queue will always be at its very front element.

#### Implementation in Python

```python
from collections import deque
from itertools import accumulate

# 1 <= a <= b <= n
n, a, b = map(int, input().split(" "))
prefix_sums = list(accumulate(map(int, input().split(" ")), initial=0))

d = b - a
# elements like `(pre_sums[i], i)`,  decreasing in the
# `pref_sums[i]` part but increasing in the `i` part.
deq = deque()
answer = -1 << 63
for i in range(a, n + d + 1):
    if deq and deq[0][1] < i - d:
        deq.popleft()
    if i <= n:
        while deq and deq[-1][0] <= prefix_sums[i]:
            deq.pop()
        deq.append((prefix_sums[i], i))
    if i >= b:
        # deq[0][0] is the maximum elements of pre_sums[i-d..min(n, i)]
        answer = max(answer, deq[0][0] - prefix_sums[i - b])

print(answer)
```

##### Complexity analysis

Prefix sums is computed in $O(n)$ time.
The outer `for` loop executes less than $2n$ iterations.
Each prefix sum will be put into the dequeue once and popped out at most once.
Hence, the algorithm runs in $O(n)$ time. $O(n)$-space is used; however, it can be reduced to $O(b-a+1)$ easily if input and processing are done by streaming.

Answer (score 2):

By augmenting an AVL tree you can implement a data structure that maintains a multi-set $S$ under the following $O(\log |S|)$-time operations:

- Add($S, x$): Add number $x$ to $S$.
- Offset($S, x$): Increase the value of all element in $S$ by number $x$.
- Delete($S,x$): Delete (one copy of) number $x$ from $S$
- Max($S$): Return the maximum element of $S$.

Let  $n$ be the number of elements in the input array, and call $a_i$ the $i$-th element. Let $\beta$ be a parameter, and define $\sigma_i$ as the maximum sum of the elements of a subarray that ends with $a_i$ and has length between $1$ and $\beta$. You can compute all values $\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n$ in time $O(n \log(1+\beta))$ as follows:

- Initialize $S=\emptyset$, and $\ell=0$.
- For $i=1, \dots,n$:

  - If $i > \beta$:

    - Delete($S$, $\ell$)
    - Decrement $\ell$ by $a_{i-\beta}$
  - Offset($S, a_i$)
  - Add($S, a_i$)
  - Increment $\ell$ by $a_i$
  - Set $\sigma_i$ to Max($S$)

At the end of the generic $i$-th iteration, the multi-set $S$ contains the sum of the elements of the contiguous (non-empty) subarrays ending with $a_i$ and having length at most $\beta$, while $\ell$ is the sum of the elements in the subarray ending with $a_i$ and having length $\min\{\beta,i\}$.

To solve your problem it suffices to compute all $\sigma_i$ for $\beta=b-a+1$ in time $O(\log (b-a+1))$ and return:
$$
\max_{i=a,\dots,n} \left\{  \sigma_{i-a+1} + \sum_{j=i-a+2}^{i} a_j \right\}.
$$
Notice that, once the values $\sigma_i$ are known, this latter maximum can be evaluated in time $O(n)$ (since each sum can be found in constant time by updating the value of the previous sum). The overall time complexity is therefore $O(n \log (b-a+1))$.